# Bzip2 package install and configure with sbmanager

Tags: apt

This is driving me crazy

I'm trying to install sbmanager
And I've done this

```
 Cd sbmanager
 ./autogen.sh
```

Checking for libbz2... no

So I tryed running this

```
 Apt-get build-dep libbz2-dev
```

But it says the following packages replace it bzip2...
Bzip2 is installed

```
Locate bzip2 
Found 34 different bzip in 6 locations
```

I don't understand the whole consider adjusting the PKG CONFIG PATH environment variable if you installed software in a nonstandard prefix...

I have no idea how to do this ->

Alternatively, you may set the environment variable libbz2_Cflags and libbz2_libs  to avoid the need to call pkg-config

I found this online,
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/21048852-libbz2-does-not-provide-pkg-config

Very bottom comment says he fixed this but what is he talking about, he didn't explain himself or I just don't understand well enough yet...

Can someone please explain in detail, cause I'm sure it would help a lot of people out that are trying to understand this...why would my system say you have it , but a program says you need it ?

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive, so please don't capitalize command names since it can lead to confusion like thinking you might have entered the wrong commands.

Comment: Rythmbox still won't detect my iphone, I installed libimobiledevice, ideviceinstaller, rythmbox-plugins, libmlbiledevice-utils, libimobiledevice-dev, is there something I'm missing cause 2 icons about my iPhone are on the desktop and it pairs fine to my phone, I configured /etc/fuse.conf, I'm slowly learning but this is insane ...do I need to modify the rythmbox script somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all [sbmanager](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/sbmanager) is waaaaay really old, last someone wrote about them was on years 2010, while the last update on 2012. I suggest you install [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) the newer version of sbmanager. Quote from "About" section.

> It allows other software to easily access the device's filesystem, retrieve information about the device and it's internals, backup/restore the device, **manage SpringBoard® icons**, manage installed applications, retrieve addressbook/calendars/notes and bookmarks and (using libgpod) synchronize music and video to the device.

Run following command to install `libimobiledevice`.

```
wget http://www.libimobiledevice.org/downloads/libimobiledevice-1.2.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf Downloads/libimobiledevice-1.2.0.tar.bz2
cd libimobiledevice-1.2.0/
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

**Note**

To get it work, make sure you have these required software.

```
usbmuxd
make
autoheader
automake
autoconf
libtool
pkg-config
gcc
```

Comment: I'm glad you said something because I've been reading forums like these https://ubuntuforums.org/archieve/index.php/t-1471018.html...with rythmbox is installed and not detecting my iPhone and I have both ideviceinstaller and libimobiledevice, I just assumed sbmanager was why it wasn't detecting it on rythmbox

Comment: `libimobildevice` is in Canonical's repositories. No need to build from source unless you need a bleeding edge version.